# difficulty in numbering the equation properly when used in subequation along with split

Tags: equations, subequations, split

Don't understand why there is some extra equation number which is coming in the last line of the equation

```
 \begin{subequations}
    \label{eq: non dimensional lagrangian}
     \begin{align}
     \mathcal{L}&=\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{V} \nonumber \\
       \mathcal{V}&=\frac{EI_{zz}}{2L}\, \int_{0}^{1} \hspace{-0.05in} \left(\frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}\right)^2 \mathrm{d}\eta +\frac{L^2}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\,k_{1,j}\left(\psi(\eta)\right)^2 \nonumber\\
        \mathcal{T}&=\frac{\rho A\omega^2L^3}{2}\, \int_{0}^{1}  \hspace{-0.05in} \left( \psi(\eta)\right)^2 \mathrm{d}\eta \nonumber \\
        \begin{split}
     \mathcal{\bar{L}}&=\frac{\beta^4}{2}\, \int_{0}^{1}  \hspace{-0.05in} \left( \psi(\eta)\right)^2 \mathrm{d}\eta-\frac{1}{2}\, \int_{0}^{1} \hspace{-0.05in} \left(\frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}\right)^2 \mathrm{d}\eta\\ &\quad{}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\,K_{1,j}\left(\psi(\eta)\right)^2    
     \end{split}\\ \nonumber \\
     \end{align}
     \end{subequations}
```

Comment: Remove the last ``\\``

Comment: and how to bring the equation number to the last line, now it is on somewhat upper

Comment: Don't use `split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong `\\` in your input.

If you want the number to sit next to the last line, don't use `split`:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq: non dimensional lagrangian}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} &= \mathcal{T}-\mathcal{V} \nonumber \\
\mathcal{V} &= \frac{EI_{zz}}{2L} \int_{0}^{1} \left(
                 \frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}
               \right)^2 \diff\eta +
               \frac{L^2}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n} k_{1,j}(\psi(\eta))^2 \nonumber \\
\mathcal{T} &= \frac{\rho A\omega^2L^3}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (\psi(\eta))^2 \diff\eta \nonumber \\
\bar{\mathcal{L}} &= \frac{\beta^4}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (\psi(\eta))^2 \diff\eta -
                     \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \left(
                       \frac{\partial^2\psi(\eta)}{\partial \eta^2}
                     \right)^2 \diff\eta \nonumber \\
                  &\quad-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}K_{1,j}(\psi(\eta))^2    
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

I've made some changes to your input, in particular removing useless `\left` and `\right`. Also `\mathcal{\bar{L}}`, while yielding the expected result, should be `\bar{\mathcal{L}}` which is sounder on a logical basis.

Use `\diff` instead of explicit `\mathrm{d}` (there are many reasons to). I removed the explicit spacings you used.

[image]

You may find `split` more logical and I can agree. In this case, add the `tbtags` option when calling `amsmath` and all numbers will be aligned with the bottom line in splits.

Comment: Within `align`, I would find it more logical to nest `aligned`.  I've forgotten where the equation number is placed by default.